# Where should the DAOs go in a project structure?

Tags: .net, dao, project-structure

I am working on a project in VB.Net and need to implement the DAL. I am not quite sure where in my project is the best place to stick the DAOs. Should I stick the DAO in the same namespace as the business objects that are going to use them. Or should I lump all the DAOs together.

I have a Java background which might taint my understanding of your .Netish answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always try to keep things nice and tidy.
You should try and maintain some kind of modular design even if it's a small project. I've burnt my fingers way too often.

Example:
PG.CustomerCare.DAL <-- Data Access Layer

PG.CustomerCare.BO <-- Business Objects <-- this might replace the Services.

PG.CustomerCare.Services <-- Services to abstract the business logic, this will have a reference to the DAL

PG.CustomerCare.Client.Web <-- Only interacts with the service layer

PG.CustomerCare.Client.Winforms <-- Same here, only interacts with the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to project structure and design at this level (programming in the large), there are not many differences between .NET and Java.

When creating my DAO, I tend to keep them in their own namespace/assembly/project as Entities. This is particularly the case if they are simply [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s that have no logic in them.

Comment: I am going to implement the DAO and use DTOs between the business objects and the DAO. I am just not too sure which namespace the DAO, DTO and the interfaces should live in.

Comment: I would use an `Entities` namespace from DTOs and `DAL` for the DAO.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the scale of your design. If I have a modular design approach I tend to put DAO's in the same assembly as the corresponding business logic.

For example, if I have a letterDAO which manages the persistence of letters then I tend put that in the same assembly as the letter business logic and the letter entities under a namespace such as [company].[project].Letters . So that all the letter functionality is in one place and I can configure or replace it easier.

If I have a applicationDAO then its the same but under [company].[project].Applications etc.